# Get root object of a dynamic server response

Tags: javascript, make.com, integromat-apps

I am implementing an API that returns different root objects inside the body. For example:

```
{
   "money_expected_revenue": {
   // payload
   }
}
or
{
   "money_other_revenue": {
   // payload
   }
}
```

The module output should be the payload inside the root object. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to write a custom IML function, use the Javascript method [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to retrieve the first key-value pair, and return the value:

```
function getRootObj(body) {
    if (body && Object.entries(body).length === 1)
        return Object.entries(body)[0][1];
    return {};
}
```

Then, in the module's Communication tab, use this function in the output:

```
"response": {
    "output": "{{getRootObj(body)}}"
}
```